# LXC guest OS installation

Tags: centos6, centos7, lxc

I have created a LXC virtualized physical server with Centos 6.8 as host OS. 
Now when I am creating guest VM using the default template of Centos, it is creating the VM's with Centos 6.8 as the guest OS. 
I wanted to create a VM with Centos 7.2 version as the guest OS. Is this possible?

I have done the below steps for creating the VM and starting.

1. Created a copy of the centos template and hard coded the 7.2 version
   inside the template. (As I understand it checks for /etc/os-release for CPE ID)
2. Created a guest VM pointing to this new template created. ( Centos 7.2 version was downloaded and placed in the LXC cache)
3. Guest VM is created. I changed the network link in the config file to bridge network.
4. I started the guest VM, But I can see only systemd process is started (using `pstree` command), there is no IP address assigned to the VM and I am not able to login to guest VM.

I needed a VM with Centos 7.2 in this environment. Please guide on how to achieve this.

Comment: LXC uses the same kernel as the host, _afaik_ you can't run a newer kernel on an "old" host.

Comment: @Lenniey I have updated the kernel to 4.10 (centos 6.8) while I have done the LXC configuration (Host system). The kernel which Centos 7 is using is 3.10.

Comment: Sorry, I was not being clear: the kernel has to be the same, not "newer", for full functionality as far as I know. Maybe there are some tricks / workarounds, but I never did such a thing myself.

Comment: @Lenniey Thanks for making it clear. I would consider upgrading my host server to centos 7.2 as a last option. But looking for some workarounds at the VM level to avoid this

Comment: Try this: https://stgraber.org/2013/12/23/lxc-1-0-some-more-advanced-container-usage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked the lxc template of CentOS to support CentOS 7.

A copy of the lxc template I have created is placed at https://github.com/nirmalraj17/lxc/blob/master/templates/lxc-centos.in

This was done because there was some steps which was related to OS version 7 which was not mentioned in the current lxc-centos template, and it was mentioned in lxc-oracle template. I took out the relevant sections out of the lxc-oracle and added it to the current lxc-centos template and created a new template named lxc-centos-7.

Then create a lxc container using the command

```
lxc-create -n centos7 -t /usr/local/share/lxc/templates/lxc-centos-7  -- -R 7
```

This will download necessary files required for release version 7

After this if you try to start the LXC container, you will receive **"[!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object, freezing."** when you try to start.

Now create a directory **systemd** under /cgroup

Mount using the below command.

```
 mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /cgroup/systemd
```

Now if you start the LXC container and tried to login, you will receive the error message "**server refused to allocate pty**"

To avoid that stop the container and create a shell script which will do the necessary actions.

```
[root@centos ~]# vi /usr/local/var/lib/{container_name}/rooftfs/usr/local/bin/device_initiation.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    mknod -m 600 /dev/console c 5 1 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 2>/dev/null
    mount -n -t tmpfs none /dev 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 622 /dev/console c 5 1 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 666 /dev/tty c 5 0 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 444 /dev/random c 1 8 2>/dev/null
    mknod -m 444 /dev/urandom c 1 9 2>/dev/null
    chown root:tty /dev/{console,ptmx,tty} 2>/dev/null
    ln -s /proc/self/fd /dev/fd 2>/dev/null
    ln -s /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/stdin 2>/dev/null
    ln -s /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null
    ln -s /proc/self/fd/2 /dev/stderr 2>/dev/null
    ln -s /proc/kcore /dev/core 2>/dev/null
    mkdir /dev/pts 2>/dev/null
    mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
    mount -t devpts -o gid=4,mode=620 none /dev/pts 2>/dev/null
    mount -t tmpfs none /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
```

Since we are placing this file in usr/local/bin, this command will be accessible from the system directly.

Now to startup the server and execute this shell script, I have created a shell script.

```
[root@centos ~]# vi startup_centos7.sh
#!/bin/bash
lxc-start -n centos7
lxc-attach -n centos7 device_initiation.sh
exit
```

Once you execute the script, the CentOS 7 will be starting and you will be able to login smoothly.

After doing the above steps, I got working CentOS 7.3 version installed on new LXC container.

Comment: Also execute the steps mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/891959/414008 to avoid the "No more ptys error for normal users"