# Unable to run Expect " no more ptys. " as normal user

Tags: centos, tty

I have an LXC container with CentOS 7.4 running. 
On running expect from Normal user I am getting the below error.

```
user@server ~>  expect -c "spawn ls"
spawn ls
The system has no more ptys.  Ask your system administrator to create more.
    while executing
"spawn ls"
```

But if we execute the same from root user, It works.

```
[root@server]#  expect -c "spawn ls"
spawn ls
```

The output of mount also have these in mount point.
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,seclabel,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)

I have ran the below updates in the server.

```
mknod -m 600 /dev/console c 5 1 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 2>/dev/null
mount -n -t tmpfs none /dev 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 622 /dev/console c 5 1 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 666 /dev/tty c 5 0 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 444 /dev/random c 1 8 2>/dev/null
mknod -m 444 /dev/urandom c 1 9 2>/dev/null
chown root:tty /dev/{console,ptmx,tty} 2>/dev/null
ln -s /proc/self/fd /dev/fd 2>/dev/null
ln -s /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/stdin 2>/dev/null
ln -s /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null
ln -s /proc/self/fd/2 /dev/stderr 2>/dev/null
ln -s /proc/kcore /dev/core 2>/dev/null
mkdir /dev/pts 2>/dev/null
mkdir /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
mount -t devpts -o gid=4,mode=620 none /dev/pts 2>/dev/null
mount -t tmpfs none /dev/shm 2>/dev/null
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

But still I am not able to run the expect command as a normal user. 
I have some scripts which needs to be run as normal user with expect statements.

I have done all possible ways which I can think of. Please help!!

Comment: How did you create this container?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i have created the container mentioned in this link. https://serverfault.com/q/848966/414008

Comment: That doesn't look right. You ought to be able to configure this in the LXC config file  `/usr/local/share/lxc/templates/lxc-centos-7` that you created. Please post a copy of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : I have added it here https://github.com/nirmalraj17/lxc/blob/master/templates/lxc-centos.in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching, I found that I needed to create the /dev/ptmx and /dev/pts structures inside the chroot.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 mknod /dev/ptmx c 5 2
 chmod 666 /dev/ptmx
 mkdir /dev/pts
 chmod 755 /dev/pts
 mount -t devpts -o gid=5,mode=620 none /dev/pts
```

Thanks to the website https://mintcast.org/building-linux/
I have quoted the script and the details from the above site.

After executing the script, I was able to execute the command

```
[user@server]#  expect -c "spawn ls"
spawn ls
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to recompile your current Kernel... Just make sure you have `CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y` and `CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS=y` in your Kernel `.config` file.

Comment: Each time I build LFS I come here, only the last command is needed in my case `mount -t devpts -o gid=5,mode=620 none /dev/pts`

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the chroot environment, but for anyone else coming across this problem, check in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` that SELinux isn't blocking access. I was having this problem even though the program was being run by root, and found this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1560463619.636:16181): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=32466
comm="myscript.exp" name="ptmx" dev="devtmpfs" ino=1149 scontext=system_u:system_r:fail2ban_t:s0
tcontext=system_u:object_r:ptmx_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
```

Using `audit2allow` I was able to generate a policy to allow my script to work.

Comment: May be true, but the issue was seen in containers created from LXC virtualization. For automation purpose, I have used "expect" command, so it need to run as regular user. For root user it was working fine. I have used normal commands only not any scripts.